# redirect reverse with kwarg; pattern not found, but url works

Tags: python, django

I try to redirect to a url on some condition and get the following error:

**Error:**

> Reverse for 'HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/nl/payments/mollie/invoice-payment-success/3248db26-fdce-4590-a5b9-9314fe30019c/">' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
>
> [08/Aug/2019 12:55:17] "GET /nl/payments/mollie/checkout/3248db26-fdce-4590-a5b9-9314fe30019c/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10956

However when I test the url in address bar it works fine.

Here's my redirect:

```
if obj.status == obj.PAID:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('payments:success_invoice_payment', kwargs={'uuid': invoice.uuid}))
```

and urls:

```
path('mollie/invoice-payment-success/<uuid>/', SuccessInvoicePayment.as_view(),
            name="success_invoice_payment"
        )
```

Any tips are much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the project structure, full urls.py for this and whatever includes this app.urls.py?

Comment: Please also post the *full* error message.

Comment: the redirect line cannot give you this error. the error contains a url, so it comes from somewhere else in your code. Please submit the full error trace as @DanielRoseman says.

Comment: I added full error

Comment: the error says "reverse for HttpResponseRedirect" so somewhere your code is using the return value to build another url. You're not showing the full error, because I don't see the line numbers and file names of where the error occurs. Again, it's not on the line `return HttpResponseRedirect` but on the line of the function that processes this return value. Actually the error proves that your reverse works as expected since it could construct the url.

Comment: is this snippet of code by any chance inside a  `def get_success_url()` or something like that?

Comment: @dirkgroten, you are right. How stupid. " somewhere your code is using the return value to build another url" <-- that is exctly it.

Comment: voting to close because the question as it stands cannot really help others and is due to a simple logic error.